# Can not show Polyline on the Android

Tags: android, google-maps, runtime-error, polyline

Sorry with my English.

I am developing my application about area detection.
I want to detect the position of android device via GPS, when it on the Polyline,it will alert the user. So I want to keep the Polyline in Local Storage.

But I do not know how to keep it?

My solution is:

- I keep the start and end point(latitude,longitude) in my database and then I will send the argument to maps.google.com and access the node then writing the Document and create Polyline from the document

Mistake
- It can not run after click "Risk Zone" It show only marker on the map but do not show the Polyline. And It will crash.

MainActivity

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.GroundOverlayOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.R.color;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap mMap;  
    GoogleMapOptions option;
    double lat=0;
    double lng=0;   
    Direction md;
    LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(13.687140112679154, 100.53525868803263);
    LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(13.683660045847258, 100.53900808095932);
    PolylineOptions rectLine;   



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();





        Button buttonNormal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonNormal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            }
        });

        Button buttonSatellite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        buttonSatellite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            }
        });

        Button buttonTerrain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        buttonTerrain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            }
        });

        Button buttonHybrid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        buttonHybrid.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            }
        });

        Button buttonLocate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        buttonLocate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                double lat =  location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();
                LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        (coordinate), 15));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(coordinate)
                        .title("Prove")
                        .snippet("Family")
                        .draggable(true)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));                

                mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        arg0.remove();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Remove Marker" + String.valueOf(arg0.getId()),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            }
        });


        /*Button buttonPoly = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        buttonPoly.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().add(
                        new LatLng(lat, lng))
                        .add(new LatLng(lat + 0.00001, lng + 0.0001));

                mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
            }
        });*/

        Button buttonDest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        buttonDest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(13.685400079263206, 100.537133384495975);       
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 15));

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fromPosition).title("Start"));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(toPosition).title("End"));

                md=new Direction();         

                Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, md.MODE_DRIVING);
                int duration = md.getDurationValue(doc);
                String distance = md.getDistanceText(doc);
                String start_address = md.getStartAddress(doc);
                String copy_right = md.getCopyRights(doc);

                ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
                PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);

                for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {          
                    rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                }

                mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);


            }
        });




    }
}
```

Direction.java

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class Direction {
    public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
    public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

    public Direction(){

    }

    public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
                }

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }

        return listGeopoints;
    }

    private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
            if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"



    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment     
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_normal"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_satellite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_terrain"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_hybrid"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/btn_locate"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_destination"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.Disthanitian.thaistyle.EmerMez"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission 
            android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <permission 
        android:name="com.example.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="app.Disthanitian.thaistyle.EmerMez.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="AIzaSyBzRmlT-LnuOeDHpxByJJVq8cxc39JTDGg"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
      06-06 10:35:34.032: I/ADM(1710): 2:   825935789: [INFO] hw_handler_u8500:849 Query: SELECT * FROM HW_Settings WHERE (Platform = 'AB8500') AND ('REF_Speaker_Playback_Music' IN (Dev1, Dev2, Dev3, Dev4, Dev5, Dev6))ORDER BY rowid LIMIT 1
06-06 10:35:34.052: W/System.err(6196): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-06 10:35:34.052: W/System.err(6196):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
06-06 10:35:34.052: W/System.err(6196):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
06-06 10:35:34.052: W/System.err(6196):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-06 10:35:34.062: W/System.err(6196):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-06 10:35:34.062: W/System.err(6196):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
06-06 10:35:34.062: W/System.err(6196):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-06 10:35:34.062: W/System.err(6196):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-06 10:35:34.062: W/System.err(6196):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-06 10:35:34.062: W/System.err(6196):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-06 10:35:34.062: W/System.err(6196):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-06 10:35:34.072: W/System.err(6196):     at app.Disthanitian.thaistyle.EmerMez.Direction.getDocument(Direction.java:41)
06-06 10:35:34.072: W/System.err(6196):     at app.Disthanitian.thaistyle.EmerMez.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:175)
06-06 10:35:34.072: W/System.err(6196):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
06-06 10:35:34.072: W/System.err(6196):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
06-06 10:35:34.072: W/System.err(6196):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-06 10:35:34.072: W/System.err(6196):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-06 10:35:34.072: W/System.err(6196):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 10:35:34.072: W/System.err(6196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
06-06 10:35:34.072: W/System.err(6196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 10:35:34.082: W/System.err(6196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 10:35:34.082: W/System.err(6196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
06-06 10:35:34.082: W/System.err(6196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
06-06 10:35:34.082: W/System.err(6196):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 10:35:34.082: D/AndroidRuntime(6196): Shutting down VM
06-06 10:35:34.082: W/dalvikvm(6196): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c612a0)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at app.Disthanitian.thaistyle.EmerMez.Direction.getDurationValue(Direction.java:62)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at app.Disthanitian.thaistyle.EmerMez.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:176)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
06-06 10:35:34.092: E/AndroidRuntime(6196):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 10:35:34.092: I/ADM(1710): 8:   825995695: [INFO] hw_handler_u8500:961 ste_adm_hw_handler_u8500: Found matching HW-settings: devices = ('REF_Speaker_Playback_Music', '', '', '', '', ''), d2dlogical-connections = ('', '', '', '').
06-06 10:35:34.162: I/ADM(1710): 7:   826061094: [INFO] dev:429 Device Speaker is OUTPUT
06-06 10:35:34.162: I/ADM(1710): 9:   826061186: [INFO] dev_omx:1276 Enter dev_omx_setup_graph - device=Speaker, samplerate=44100, format=2, alloc_buffers=0, is_vc=0, bufsz=0
06-06 10:35:34.162: E/android.os.Debug(2035): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: your English looks good :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Direction.java seems f9... but u need to modify the **MainActivity** , the code you're trying to execute **on button click**.. run it through AsynTask (ie create a private class that must extend the AsyncTask) and call the execute() of this asyn-class on your button click...!!!

> This will surely resolve your  **06-06 10:35:34.052:
>   W/System.err(6196): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**   Error. Hopefully, this wud also resolve the exceptions following such as **"java.lang.NullPointerException"** ..because the **"doc"**- object itself might be null as the code throws an NetworkException, further giving an null response & thus leading to exceptions whereever you have a **"doc"**-obj dependency...!!!

below i have attached a code snippet that you can refer for the same..!!
Incase you wanna follow up in detail you can refer this ["show route on google-maps v2](http://prabhakarsinghblogs.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-to-draw-route-in-google-maps-api-v2.html)"

```
 private class showRoute extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document>{       
            Document doc; 
            PolylineOptions rectLine;       

                    @Override
            protected Document doInBackground(Void... params) {    
            doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);    
        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
            rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);

            for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {              
               rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
            }           
               return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Document result) {         
              mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
            }   

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code and they are not related to `Polylines`.

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

This means you are trying to run blocking code on main thread. You need to use `AsyncTask`, `Thread`, executors or other means of not blocking user interface.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Somewhere inside your `Direction.getDurationValue` (exactly on line 62) you are trying to call a method on `null` reference.